# How to sum all the input values of more than one cells in the last cell of table in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

So I need to calculate the sum of input values for each input cell and show it dynamically to the last cell of the row. Refer following image
[image: Table]

In the above image the number of products can vary so rows generated are not fixed
Now as shown in the image I need to update the value of final amount for each row dynamically using input available for each row's cells

I am attaching HTML code for the table:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Sub Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Master Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Weight</th>
                            <th scope="col">Labour</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                            <th scope="col">SGST (In %)</th>
                            <th scope="col">CGST (In %)</th>
                            <th scope="col">Discount</th>
                            <th scope="col">Final Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let item of _selectedProductsData;index as i">
                            <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
                            <td>{{item.productCategory}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.subCategory}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.masterCategory}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.productWeight}} gms</td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control labourInput" type="number" id="{{item.productGuid}}-labour"
                                    placeholder="Enter Labour">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control priceInput" type="number" id="{{item.productGuid}}-price"
                                    placeholder="Enter Price">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control sgstInput" type="number" id="{{item.productGuid}}-SGST"
                                    placeholder="Enter SGST">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control cgstInput" type="number" id="{{item.productGuid}}-CGST"
                                    placeholder="Enter CGST">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control discountInput" type="number"
                                    id="{{item.productGuid}}-discount" placeholder="Enter Discount">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{calculateTotalAmountOfEachProduct(item.productGuid)}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

each row (product) has its own productGuid

I've created method `calculateTotalAmountOfEachProduct(productGuid:string)` but it does not change the value it always shows 0 even when input value is changed
Following is the code for the same:

```
  calculateTotalAmountOfEachProduct(productGuid:string):number {
    let labourInput = Number((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(`${productGuid}-labour`)).value)
    let priceInput = Number((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(`${productGuid}-price`)).value)
    let sgstInput = Number((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(`${productGuid}-SGST`)).value)
    let cgstInput = Number((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(`${productGuid}-CGST`)).value)
    let discountInput = Number((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(`${productGuid}-discount`)).value)
    return labourInput+priceInput+sgstInput+cgstInput+discountInput
  }
```

I am not sure how to achieve this in angular.

Comment: You should read the guide to forms from the official website: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Actually i know how the forms in angular works..But the number of input tags will be variable so that is where I am stuck.Anyways thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of achieving what you are asking, you could do it using local references on each input, and then listening for the `input` event for changes in the values like the following:

This is just an example:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Labour</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">SGST (In %)</th>
      <th scope="col">CGST (In %)</th>
      <th scope="col">Discount</th>
      <th scope="col">Final Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index">
      <th>{{ i + 1 }}</th>
      <th><input type="number" (input)="d.labor = getValue($event)" #labor [value]="d.labor" /></th>
      <th><input type="number" (input)="d.price = getValue($event)" #price [value]="d.price" /></th>
      <th><input type="number" (input)="d.sgst = getValue($event)" #sgst [value]="d.sgst" /></th>
      <th><input type="number" (input)="d.cgst = getValue($event)" #cgst [value]="d.cgst" /></th>
      <th><input type="number" (input)="d.discount = getValue($event)" #discount [value]="d.discount" /></th>
      <th>
        <!-->the plus sign is for casting from string to number<-->
        <label
          >{{ +labor.value + +price.value + +sgst.value + +cgst.value + +discount.value }}
        </label>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**component**

```js
@Component({...})
export class DemoComponent {
  data = [...] // some data
  
  getValue(event: Event): number {
    return Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  }
}
```

Here's the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eum54e?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fmain.html,src%2Fmain.scss)

Comment: Thank you for the reply..But my data does not contain properties for labour,cgst etc..Actually that is this whole thing is about...The data should be entered and initialized by the user

Comment: Make the inputs have an initial value of 0 if they don't have values..., that's it... after that, if the user enters valid numbers, then it works